# Navigate a Map[String, Any] in Scala

Tags: scala

How to navigate in a Map[String, Any] in Scala ?

e.g.: `map.get('key1,key2')`

Which will be equivalent of `map.get('key1').get('key2')`.

But what i want to do is `'key1,key2'.split(',')` and navigate in the Map.

Is this possible?

P.S.: I have this made in Java, but it's like `if value instanceof Map` cast to Map, get the new value and recursive call the `get` with remaining tokens.

Comment: Is this perhaps a json input that you've parsed into a Map[String, Any]? You'll be much better served by parsing that input into a case class and then be able to rely on the type safety.

Comment: No, it's not a Json Input. What i want is the equivalent of a Ruby Hash

Comment: *But what i want to do is 'key1,key2'.split(',') and navigate in the Map.* What does that mean?

Comment: "What I want is the equivalent of a Ruby Hash" sounds weird. If you like using ruby hashes, why write scala?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps i didn't explain myself right. I want to be able to navigate in the Map like a Tree (including Nested Maps). The Ruby Hash analogy is like ['key1']['key2']. I'm trying to rewrite Ruby code in Scala. Ruby is just too slow

Comment: @Diver (part of) the reason it is slow is dynamic typing you are trying to implement ...

Comment: some of the Scala JSON libraries allow path based navigation like that, can you data be represented as JSON?

Comment: The thing is, i'm trying to implement "Accessors" for the Map which will be configurable by the user through a config file.

Comment: have you looked at `scala.Dynamic`?

Comment: I'm trying to do something like [this](https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/master/logstash-core-event-java/src/main/java/com/logstash/Accessors.java#L125)

Comment: The reason it is difficult to answer this, is that in scala you would not typically work with a `Map[String,Any]` as it is unsafe. Normally you would create a more strict data structure to represent the data. Something like `RuleSet` with values specified by a sealed hierarchy. More details about the actual domain would help give a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, I think, this is a very wrong thing to do, but, if you insist, here you go:

```
   implicit def toMap(m: Any) = m.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
   Map[String,Any]("foo" -> Map("bar" -> Map("baz" -> 3)))("foo")("bar")("baz")
   res15: Any = 3
```

Comment: How else will I make it configurable by the user?

Comment: Make _what_ "configurable"?

Comment: I'm trying to build a rules engine where that map will be filled with values, including nested maps and the user will implement the Rules in json like "FieldReference" -> Rules to apply

Comment: Rules should have a data model and be represented by a data structure, not `Map`

Comment: And how do I apply rules over structured data? Deserialized Json Object random generic data?

Comment: Depends on what kind of rules they are, and what kind of data it is :)